# Convert a GET to a POST in PHP Woocommerce with redirect

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a Woocommerce plugin which collects form data and then does this:

```
$my_query  =  http_build_query($post_data, '', '&');
$my_url = $this->MV_URL.$my_query;
header('Location:'.$my_url );
```

Which redirects the page to my https://mycoolsite.com?name=simon&product=phone

Which is ok but...

What I'd like to do is not have the personal info in the URL as parameters but instead convert this to a POST from a GET request.

What I have tried is this:

```
$result = wp_remote_post( $this->MV_URL, $post_data );
```

But that isn't redirecting the page like it did before.

Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to understand what post and get does.

**POST:** To send data
**GET:** To get data

Ideally sending data via URL params (query strings) will be treated as GET. But in your case you do base64_encode your personal data and decode your data once you get on the receiving end base64_decode

Do something like to send and encode

```
$EncodedName = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode('Simon'), '+/', '-_'), '=');
$EncodedProduct = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode('Phone'), '+/', '-_'), '=');
```

GET it like and decode

```
$DecodedName = base64_decode(strtr($_GET['name'], '-_', '+/'));  
$DecodedName = base64_decode(strtr($_GET['product'], '-_', '+/'));
```

If you do not want to do above method of encoding and decoding (securing data) then you have use FORMDATA (jquery ajax request) to do a post request on that redirect URL you have.

Hope it helps.